# Craft calculator loop

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do a craft calculator for a game.

I have a database who looks like this :

Crafts :

```
id    item_id   item_name    amount
 3     1895         a          5
 8     2486         c          1
```

Craft_materials :

```
id    craft_id   item_id    item_name   amount
 1       3        2486          c         15
 2       3        5302          d         23
 3       3        5698          e          2
 4       8        2014          f          3
```

And here is my query to retrieve the data :

```
$craftProduct = $db->query("SELECT * FROM crafts WHERE item_id=$item");
$craftProduct->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$product = $craftProduct->fetch();

$craftID = $product->id;

$craftMaterial = $db->query("SELECT * FROM craft_materials WHERE craft_id=$craftID");
$craftMaterial->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

echo '<ul>';
    echo '<li>'.$product->item_name.' ('.$product->amount.')</li>';
        echo '<ul>';
        while($material = $craftMaterial->fetch()){
             echo '<li>'.$material->item_name.' ('.$material->amount.')</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
echo '</ul>';
```

What I want to do is take the material id and check if it corresponds with a craft. If it does, I want to show the material needed to craft it.

I want something which looks like this :

```
- a (5)
    - c (15)
        - f (3)
    - d (23)
    - e (2)
```

However, I don't know how to do the loop. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic recursion setup:

```
function render_item($item_id) {
    $product = fetch_item($item_id);    // select from crafts where item_id = $item_id
    $children = "";
    foreach (fetch_children($product->id) as $child_id) { // select from craft_mats where craft_id = $product->id
        $children .= render_item($child_id);
    }
    echo "<li>" . $product->item_name . "<ul>" . $children . "</ul></li>";
}

echo "<ul>" . render_item(1895) . "</ul>"
```